# two hands arpegiato : simultaneously or left first, followed by right hand?

Tags: piano, chords, technique, arpeggios

In this score (*Danse Macabre*, Saint-Saëns/Liszt)
there is an arpeggiated chord across the two hands: should it be done simultaneously or done first with left hand, followed by right hand?

[image: mm. 14–19]

Comment: Another similar example is Chopin Ballade No 1 Bar 7. There's a left hand arpeggio and a single note on the right hand. Some play it as a single arpeggio (RH note after the LH arpeggio) others play them simultaneously (RH note with the first note of the LH arpeggio).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a short accented chord and the the two arpeggio lines are separated so it would be logical to play both hands simultaneously. If the composer had intended the hands to be played one after the other he could have written just a single arpeggio-line.
On Horowitz's recording of the piece he appears to play the hands separately:

It probably doesn't matter either way: do what you feel sounds good.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand your answer : do you mean that :
-from the score, it should be played the two hands simultaneously
-Horowitz plays one hand after the other, so in disagreement with the "written score"

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian Yes I interpret the score to mean simultaneously, but Horowitz seems to separates the hands. Either way works.

Comment: many thanks for the help

Comment: But that said, it is a bit strange, about the notation : indeed in Chopin Etude 11, Opus 10, it is clear tha tthe arpeggio lines should be played "sequentially" (left hand, followed by right hand) while it is "written" simultaneously.

Comment: we see clearly for example in Chopin that it is played sequentlially (while the score does not write in this direction) example : https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=chopin+etude+11+opus+10#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:98355f93,vid:QwHbC7CeW5o,st:0

Comment: so there is the possible explanation that it is too much difficult (in term of "edition" to write the arpeggio symbol linking the left and right hand)

Answer (score 3):

Since the wiggly arp. line is separated, both hands should be played simultaneously. Were it meant to be l.h. then r.h., the wiggly line would be joined, making it one continuous, a graphic illustration of what's intended. However, 'poetic licence' gives some leeway to the performer, which is why there are differing versions to be heard. (Ref. pg. 132 of 'Behind Bars', Gould).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the possibility of some typesetting constraint or error, and in addition to recorded performances by respected pianists, I would also look at the "function" of the notes. If played simultaneously, it'd give an arpeggio in parallel octaves (an interesting effect), while if played separately it would just be a repetition of the same blocky chord an octave higher. The latter is less interesting to *me* than the illusion (?) of an arpeggio in octaves. :)  Also, the immediately preceding measures did *not* have the two hands echoing each other. But, not in parallel, either, so... it's hard to know the composer's intent.